# How to test equality of directionsService request objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API v3 and I want to reduce the number of API requests I'm making to a minimum.

It would make sense for me to store the last request made and test the next being equal to the last, ignoring it if true:

```
var request = {
    origin: "John O'Groats",
    destination: "Land's End",
    waypoints: [{
        location: "Penrith",
        stopover: true
    }],
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
// Dont make a new request if same as last
if (request !== lastRequest) {
    lastRequest = request;
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {

            ...

    }
}
```

The above didn't work.

So I tried `JSON.stringify`:

```
if (JSON.stringify(request) !== JSON.stringify(lastRequest)) {
```

Still no dice.

Then I tried the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) `isEqual` function:

```
if (!_.isEqual(request, lastRequest)) {
```

Again not working.

All the above return incorrect results. I'm guessing perhaps because `wpts` is another object within the `request` object.

How should I test equality of these two objects in javascript?

### Solution

Beetroot-Beetroot's answer put me on the right track

> As there's only one object then any attempt to compare lastRequest
>   with request will always yield true - can't be anything else. Even if
>   the properties of the object have changed, you will still be comparing
>   the changed object with itself.

Storing the stringified version of the request for later testing solved my problem:

```
var request = {
    origin: "John O'Groats",
    destination: "Land's End",
    waypoints: [{
        location: "Penrith",
        stopover: true
    }],
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
},
    requestStr = JSON.stringify(request);
// Dont make a new request if same as last
if (requestStr !== lastRequest) {
    lastRequest = requestStr;
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {

            ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Object's equality isin't based on object properties at all. `o1 === o2` will only evaluate to `true` if it's the same object instance. What properties do you want to check to know wheter both objects are equal?

Comment: At a minimum I need to ensure that `origin`, `destination` and `waypoints` are different.  I did think about storing these as separate vars - is this the way to go?

Comment: What's the structure of a waypoint?

Comment: It's an array of objects `array({location: location, stopover: true})`

Comment: I'll setup a real sample if you cannot work it out with what I posted. I just dont have enough time right now.

Comment: Why did you select this answer? I took a look at your fiddle and you are defining new `request` objects or every request so the solution you selected has **nothing to do with your issue at all**. You should not need to `JSON.stringify` or `_.extend` from what I've seen. That's unless the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvwA/2/) you posted is not correctly showing how you construct `request` objects.

Comment: @plalx Answer was selected because it provided the information I needed to solve the problem. The fiddle I posted is pretty much exactly how I construct request objects, less the example code you provided.  I appreciate your efforts and thank you for them, however it didn't help me to solve the problem I had.

Comment: In that case you have the wrong solution and you do not need `JSON.stringify` at all. You should post another fiddle that really reflects your real code and we will find the issue.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvwA/7/ shows the solution working as intended.

Comment: I am not sure what you were doing initially, but it works very well with `_.isEqual` just like I expected. Have a look at the modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvwA/8/). The answer you accepted is completely wrong and it's assumptions are totally wrong as well. `"you will still be comparing the changed object with itself"` is **not** a true statement, because you are reconstructing a **new** `request` object everytime you are calling the function. It's easy to prove, just add `console.log(request === lastRequest)` and it **always** evaluate to false.

Comment: However, comparing stringified versions of the objects is an alternative to `_.isEqual` to perform a deep compare of two objects. You must have changed your code since you first posted the question because using `_.isEqual` or `JSON.stringify` should have worked back then. Anyway, my point is just that the accepted answer has nothing to do with the solution at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem lies in `lastRequest = request`.

Javascript objects are assigned by reference not value, so `lastRequest = request` simply creates a second symbol (`lastRequest`) pointing to the same object as the original symbol (`request`).

As there's only one object then any attempt to compare `lastRequest` with `request` will always yield `true` - can't be anything else. Even if the properties of the object have changed, you will still be comparing the changed object with itself.

However ...

jQuery includes the great utility `$.extend()`, which (used in the right way) allows javascript objects to be cloned.

Try :

```
lastRequest = $.extend({}, request);
```

Now comparing `lastRequest` with `request` will always yield `false` because `request` and `lastRequest` are different objects (regardless of their properties).

But ... try your stringify comparison. It now stands a good chance of working.

Comment: I reordered things and managed to get stringify to work without using `$.extend()` - `if (JSON.stringify(request) === lastRequest) { return; } lastRequest = JSON.stringify(request);` storing the stringified version of the request for later testing instead of the object.

Answer (score 1):

The `===` or `==` operators will only evaluate to `true` if both sides of the expression are the same object instance so you will not be able to use these operators directly to compare object's equality based on their properties.

However you could implement your own equality checking algorithm and if you want to you could use a slighlty more OO approach by having a `DirectionRequest` pseudo-class with an `equals` instance function.

```
function DirectionRequest(data) {
    this.origin = data.origin;
    this.destination = data.destination;
    this.waypoints = data.waypoints;
    this.travelMode = data.travelMode;
}

DirectionRequest.prototype.equals = function (request) {
    if (!(request instanceof this.constructor)) {
        return false;
    }

    //equality checking algorithm e.g.
    return this.origin === request.origin 
           && this.destination === request.destination;
};

var req1 = new DirectionRequest({
        origin: 'start', //just strings for the example
        destination: 'end',
        waypoints: 'wpts',
        travelMode: 'driving'
    }),
    req2 = new DirectionRequest({
        origin: 'start', //just strings for the example
        destination: 'end',
        waypoints: 'wpts',
        travelMode: 'driving'
    });

req1.equals(req2); //true
req1.equals({}); //false
```

EDIT:

I have modified the implementation slightly for your needs, have a look at the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvwA/4/). For `waypoints` you cannot simply check if `this.waypoints === request.waypoints` like you did since it will simply check if the array instances are the same object. You are better simply using `_.isEqual` which will do a deep compare between both objects.

```
DirectionRequest.prototype.equals = function(request) {
    return _.isEqual(this, request);
};
```

Comment: I tried this: 
`chkRequest = new DirectionRequest(request);
        // ...
        if (!chkRequest.equals(lastRequest)) {
            lastRequest = chkRequest;`

and added `&& this.waypoints === request.waypoints` to your equality checking algorithm but It returns true *always* - is that test valid for the waypoints object?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't what I wanted to post.  Try this instead http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvwA/2/ it returns true *always* but should only do it once.